# EF Core 5.0.10 - Multiple subqueries generated when projecting subset of a many to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

The data model I am querying has a temporal many to many relationship between workers and units as follows.

[image: Data model]

We are trying to efficiently return a list of workers with details of the active unit at a moment in time using the following linq statement.

```
            var result = filteredQuery
.Select(w => 
    new {
        Worker = w,
        FunctionalUnit = w.Linkages.FirstOrDefault(l => 
            l.Hierarchy.Type == HierarchyType.Functional
            && ( l.Start ?? DateTimeOffset.MinValue ) <= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
            && ( l.End ?? DateTimeOffset.MaxValue ) > DateTimeOffset.UtcNow).ToUnit,
    })
.Select(e => 
    new
    {
        WorkerId = e.Worker.Id, 
        FunctionalUnitId = e.FunctionalUnit.Id, 
        FunctionalUnitName=e.FunctionalUnit.Name, 
        FunctionalUnitRemoteId=e.FunctionalUnit.RemoteId
    }).ToList();
```

Although this works the generated SQL is not the most efficient.  For every property of the projected Unit in the final select, it adds another identical subquery as per below.

```
SELECT [w].[Id] AS [WorkerId], (
SELECT TOP(1) [u].[Id]
FROM [Linkages] AS [l]
INNER JOIN [Hierarchies] AS [h] ON [l].[HierarchyId] = [h].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Units] AS [u] ON [l].[ToUnitId] = [u].[Id]
WHERE ([w].[Id] = [l].[FromWorkerId]) AND ((([h].[Type] = 0) AND (COALESCE([l].[Start], '0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00') <= [i].[Now])) AND (COALESCE([l].[End], '9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999+00:00') > [i].[Now]))) AS [FunctionalUnitId], (
SELECT TOP(1) [u0].[Name]
FROM [Linkages] AS [l0]
INNER JOIN [Hierarchies] AS [h0] ON [l0].[HierarchyId] = [h0].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Units] AS [u0] ON [l0].[ToUnitId] = [u0].[Id]
WHERE ([w].[Id] = [l0].[FromWorkerId]) AND ((([h0].[Type] = 0) AND (COALESCE([l0].[Start], '0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00') <= [i].[Now])) AND (COALESCE([l0].[End], '9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999+00:00') > [i].[Now]))) AS [FunctionalUnitName], (
SELECT TOP(1) [u1].[RemoteId]
FROM [Linkages] AS [l1]
INNER JOIN [Hierarchies] AS [h1] ON [l1].[HierarchyId] = [h1].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Units] AS [u1] ON [l1].[ToUnitId] = [u1].[Id]
WHERE ([w].[Id] = [l1].[FromWorkerId]) AND ((([h1].[Type] = 0) AND (COALESCE([l1].[Start], '0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00') <= [i].[Now])) AND (COALESCE([l1].[End], '9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999+00:00') > [i].[Now]))) AS [FunctionalUnitRemoteId] FROM [Workers] AS [w] INNER JOIN [Instances] AS [i] ON [w].[InstanceId] = [i].[Id]
```

As this join is relatively expensive (approximately 75% of the cost of the query) the more properties we select from the Unit the more inefficient it becomes.  I assume this is part of the way that the SQL generation is carried out. It is relatively easy to rewrite the generated SQL query manually as a single join selecting multiple values.  Is there a way to write the Linq statement to ensure a single subquery?

I have reviewed the EF Core documentation and was unable to find anything that helped.

Comment: Just curious, if you .Select the entire `e.FunctionalUnit` does it do a `TOP 1 *` equivalent? Also, have you looked at something like `parent.Select(p => p.Children.OrderByDescending(c => c.SomeProperty).First())` which should be translated as something like a join to a subquery that does a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FKCol ORDER BY SomeProperty DESC) rn WHERE rn = 1` ?

Comment: What is `ToUnit`?

Comment: @CaiusJard, thanks for the quick response.  I tried returning the entire FunctionalUnit which does work, however does not allow the selection of only the properties we need.  I am interested in being able to only ship the properties required from the database.  Using the OrderByDescending changes the query but still leads to multiple subqueries

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, ToUnit is the Unit that the many-many relation links to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like EF Core LINQ translator still needs improvements. The following query should generate optimal SQL.

```cs
var query = 
    from w in filteredQuery
    from f in w.Linkages.Where(l => 
            l.Hierarchy.Type == HierarchyType.Functional
            && ( l.Start ?? DateTimeOffset.MinValue ) <= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
            && ( l.End ?? DateTimeOffset.MaxValue ) > DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
       .Take(1)
    select new 
    {
        WorkerId = w.Id, 
        FunctionalUnitId = f.ToUnit.Id, 
        FunctionalUnitName = f.ToUnit.Name, 
        FunctionalUnitRemoteId = f.ToUnit.RemoteId       
    }
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  I don't normally use this syntax and always assumed that the result would be the same using either.  Interestingly if I use the Take(1) syntax on the fluent Linq it still compiles the more verbose SQL output.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: Query syntax is converted by compiler to Fluent syntax. So result should be the same.